# Is there any mechanism provided by Apple Store to make the user sign-up to my website before he/she can download the application?

Tags: iphone

I am creating an iphone application that requires the users to have an account at my website.
But if i have to distribute it through apple store, how should I make the users of this Iphone Application first create an account with my website. There could be a few options like :

1) Ask the user to create an account when he/she tries to run the application on iphone.
2) Provide a 'Sign-Up' page in the Iphone application itself.

My question is "Is there any mechanism provided by Apple Store to make the user sign-up to my website before he/she can download the application".

Kindly give in your suggestions for the same. Which would be the best approach for solving my problem.

Thanks,
LG

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do this through the app store.

Yes: your two options are to create a sign in / sign up screen with cocoa, or to display your login webpage with a NSWebview.

I'd recommend the native control route...

Comment: I really think it's far more friendly to have a native login dialogs rather than a web page form - the web page form may load slowly, or even not at all if the data connection is poor.  At least with native controls they see something and you can issue an alert if there is no network.

Comment: Most apps make the initial screen a login/registration screen that you can't pass until you register/login. After that on subsequent launches you can have the login info cached in the keychain and you read it out and bypass the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that through Apples App Store.

You could provide the user with aviability to register to your site when opening your app, throug, say a NSWebView.

There are many ways to solve this, just not the one you might like.